# python remove find text from a list

Tags: python, list

How remove from list in python?

```
a=[('hello','home','today','cry'),('hello','saturday','today','cry'),('bye','home','today','cry')]
```

if find 'saturday' remove all `('hello','saturday','today','cry')`

so i have

```
a=[('hello','home','today','cry'),('bye','home','today','cry')]
```

thanks

Answer (score 6):

Use a *list comprehension* with a filter:

```
>>> [tup for tup in a if 'saturday' not in tup]
[('hello', 'home', 'today', 'cry'), ('bye', 'home', 'today', 'cry')]
```

---

Reference:

[List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 1):

I am sticking to the OP's demand of removing the item from list (not creating the new list). So, *list comprehension* is not the suggested approach. The result can be achieved using `for` loop as:

```
>>> for i, sublist in enumerate(list(a)):  # list(a) to iterate over the copy of a 
...     if 'saturday' in sublist:
...          del a[i]
...
>>> a
[('hello', 'home', 'today', 'cry'), ('bye', 'home', 'today', 'cry')]
```

Instead of iterating over `a`, I am iterating over `list(a)`, because delating the object from list on which you are iterating result into *unexpected* results.

---

In case it is OK to create new list and update with original, apart from *list comprehension* approach (which is already mentioned), you may use `filter()` as:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: 'saturday' not in x, a))
[('hello', 'home', 'today', 'cry'), ('bye', 'home', 'today', 'cry')]
```

Comment: Why not just set `a` equal to the list comprehension? This is not the pythonic way to do this.

Comment: @NickA: as per the OP, he mentioned *"remove from list"*. *List Comprehension* is creation of the new list and replacing it with the original. But I agree on the part *list comprehension is more pythonic* for this

Answer (score 0):

Turn a into a into a list of lists and then check each of the sublists for 'saturday'

```
a=[('hello','home','today','cry'),('hello','saturday','today','cry'),('bye','home','today','cry')]
a=list(a)
for x in range (len(a)-1,-1,-1):
     if 'saturday' in list(a[x]):
          a.pop(x)
```

This gives a=[('hello', 'home', 'today', 'cry'), ('bye', 'home', 'today', 'cry')]